# What’s the difference between “Go all out” and “Go all in”?

Tags: idioms, word-usage

There was the following sentence in August 12 Time magazine article titled “Why Germany save the Euro,” which deals with the Germany’s roles in restoring the momentum of Euro economy:

> “There are those in Europe and beyond who’d like to see Germany **go all
>   in** and write a blank check to the euro zone in exchange for greater
>   fiscal and ultimately political power in Brussels. But Merkel and her
>   team argue that it’s not possible to make the required financial
>   commitments without a new European constitution that allows Brussels
>   the power - - -.”

Both Cambridge English and OAEL Dictionary define ‘go all out’ in the same way as an idiom to mean “to put all one’s energy or enthusiasm into what he/she is doing,” but neither of them includes “go all in” as an idiom.

Google Ngram shows the usage of “go all out” which surfaced in circ. 1900, peaked to 0.0000125730% incidence level around 1960, and then dropping down to 0.0000079294% in 2008. On the other hand, the usage of “go all in” is almost insignificant level (0.0000003849 in 2008) throughout its tracking record.

Ngram [Go all out vs. go all in](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go+all+out%2C+go+all+in&year_start=1840&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgo%20all%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20all%20in%3B%2Cc0)

What is the difference between “go all in” and “go all out”?

Can we use “go all out” in place of “go all in,” of which currency appears to be very marginal as observed in Google Ngram, in the context of the above quote?

Comment: Perhaps adding a link to the Ngram graph would be more digestible for the "mathematically challenged" (dumb with numbers) among us, myself, first and foremost!

Comment: @Mari-Lou A. I wish I could add Ngram grapgh, but I don't know how to. So I pasted the link above.

Comment: Thank for for posting the link, the graph makes the figures so much clearer to understand. It's very dramatic!

Comment: Fumblefingers found a work around solution for posting Ngram graphs. This might be helpful to you. http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/1173/44619

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***Going all out*** is used to convey the idea of *sparing no expense*

> He really went all out for this party.

***Going all in*** is used to convey betting everything at once- *putting all your eggs in one basket* as it were.

> He really went all in on that one.  I hope he's right otherwise he'll be declaring bankruptcy tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

The main difference between the two is that "all out" just emphasizes the magnitude of someone's effort while "all in" implies the investment of all of sort of resource—monetary or other—and is therefore used to illustrate risk. Consider

> "She went all in and invested her life savings in her business. I hope that it succeeds."

vs.

> "He went all out on this project. I heard he hasn't slept on two days."

Answer (score 1):

The term and phrase **"going all in"** is derived from the card game poker, especially in the variation "Texas hold 'em."  It refers to an all or nothing bet when a player risks his entire remaining table stake on one hand.  Win, or step away from the table---you've lost.  Gambling jargon. The term has increased in usage with the rise in popularity, over the past approximately twenty-five years, of Texas hold 'em tournament play (both in the U.S. and increasingly internationally) and especially due to the game's exposure on television.  It seems to me the only significant difference between the idioms  "going all out" and  "going all in" may be the lack of enthusiasm with the latter. (10/15/2018)